# Cocos2d is not recompiling in Eclipse

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2d.
I did build the project and imported in eclipse the sample project is working fine.
But when I start to change the code e.g changing the background image file in Helloworld.cpp it is still showing the old file in emulator.
I change the whole code in helloworld.cpp enter some function for spirits and touch still same sample app is running it seems it is compiling the old file all over again.
can somebody help me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Add your .cpp files in **Android.mk** under `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` field and then execute **build_native.sh** in terminal which will compile your source files. Now build your project in eclipse and enjoy :)

Comment: What's the log against build_native.sh execution?

Comment: It always build successfully.

Comment: Can you please paste your Android.mk's content?

Comment: now this is coming $ ./build_native.sh
Using prebuilt externals
make: Entering directory '/cygdrive/e/Androide-SDK/Cocos2d/mole/proj.android'
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
make: *** No rule to make target 'jni/mole/main.cpp', needed by 'obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/mole/main.o'.  Stop.

Comment: This clearly shows your compilation failed. Please make sure you have main.cpp inside **mole** directory in **jni**. And other source files inside Classes folder and that the path is correct.